# UIImageView+AFNetworking is not retrieving latest image from server

Tags: ios, afnetworking-2

I am facing issue in image caching.I can not able to get new image. Because I am using same URL to get image. But server side my admin changed images on that URL location.

I know there is one way to check whether it is new or old based on status code or cache-controller.

**Here my question is that is there any way to get status code of URL with out downloading content ?**

Step1 : Loaded image from online url successfully. using following method

```
(void)setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholderImage; This is successfully display on my image view and cached. Step 2: I changed image from server. Url is same. So I can not able to get latest image. I am always getting old image.
```

Question: **How can I get latest image from server using UIImageView+AFNetworking category with same url?**

Note: I am getting status code from server side successfully (304 or 200). So how can I handle?

Comment: are you solved your problem? Now i am facing same problem?Have you got any solution?

Comment: No buddy, I dont get any solution.

Comment: i found solution...i modified framework...

Comment: Can you please tell me how?

Comment: every time i am comparing last modified date.If modified i am deleting from cache and downloading file..

Comment: Hi kittu, How can we check modified date ?

Comment: Please go through the link.
https://github.com/kittu4ios/DownloadUpdateImage

Comment: Thanks Let me try. I will update you

Answer (score 1):

Can you try resetting the cache of the category?? but it will remove all objects in the cache so its on you to decide whether you want all new images to be fetched at all times. Try this,

```
  [yourImageView setSharedImageCache:nil];
```

If you want to check the status code and all that you got to work on your own category for UIImageView or break up the existing category, look at this method for more details.

```
- (void)setImageWithURLRequest:(NSURLRequest *)urlRequest
              placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholderImage
                       success:(void (^)(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image))success
                       failure:(void (^)(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error))failure
```

Comment: Thanks, first of all "setSharedImageCache" is not the case because I dont know when exactly  image changed in server side so if we use this this will retrive image every time from online only. And second one, We can get status code using above method but does that give status code with out downloading content or not ?

Comment: Nope, I don't think that this method would give you the status code even before downloading.

Comment: So How can we handle this condition ?is there any alternative way ?

Comment: @HelpMeToHelpYou: Have you got any solution?

Comment: See this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17076348/how-to-check-if-have-a-new-version-of-the-image-is-available-before-download

Answer (score 1):

Try setting a cachePolicy via `NSURLRequest` like so:

```
[_yourImageView setImageWithURLRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@
    "YOUR URL"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:30.0] placeholderImage:placeholder success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
            [_yourImageView setImage:image];
        } failure:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks, But if I use cachePolicy as  NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData, this will disable whole cache mechanism. It will load every time from online. But my requirement is different, I want cache but while any change in server, It should able to find the change and than only it should start downloading .